# how to get correct time from the utc datetimestring in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to get the correct time from this `datetime` string including the am and pm in python.

eg: `2017-04-11T10:34:50.472580Z.`

I want it like this

`Apr 11, 2017 4:04:50 PM`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to use something like :

`date.strftime(format)`

*Return a string representing the date, controlled by an explicit format string. Format codes referring to hours, minutes or seconds will see 0 values. For a complete list of formatting directives, see section strftime() and strptime() Behavior.*

`date.__format__(format)`

*Same as date.strftime(). This makes it possible to specify a format string for a date object when using str.format(). See section strftime() and strptime() Behavior.*

you will find more details and examples here :

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html